# jQuery - select a element with a certain attribute from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements, in a "that" variable.
How can I find a element with a specific attribute inside these?

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){
    var that = this;
    return this.each(function(){
       $(this).bind('change', function(){
           $("[name]", that).dostuff(); // <- doesn't seem to work

           return true;
        }).change();

   });
 };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.filter()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)</sup> method should do it:

```
$(that).filter('[name]').dostuff();
```

Comment: @Alexandra: Why is it weird? I think you just have to learn some of the important methods. `$("[name]", that)` does not work, because it is the same as `that.find("[name]")` which will search for all the *descendants* of the elements in `that` which match the selector.

Comment: Btw. `that` is already a jQuery object, so `that.filter` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
var found=$(that).find("thingyousearching");
```

Comment: `find` will search all the descendants of the currently selected elements, not the elements itself.

Comment: @Felix Kling - ok. does it solves her problem? so what you suggest?

Comment: @FeRtoll: No, it does not solve her problem. Look at @jAndy's answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling - i see... so **filter** is batter than **find**? or **find** wouldnt even work?

Comment: @FeRtoll: `find` would not work. `find` would be like `$('div [name]')` which will find all elements that have a `name` attribute and are inside divs. I think the OP wants `$(div[name])`,i.e. finding all divs which have a name attribute. So assuming `that = $('div')`, `find` will do the former and `filter` the later. Please see the documentation for more information.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Please see the documentation for more information. Thank you this is what i was searching for! nm. just forget it! You wouldnt understand!

Comment: Sorry, what? http://api.jquery.com/filter/: *Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.* http://api.jquery.com/find/: *Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.*  And the documentation also provides more examples which makes it easier to understand the differences. Sorry, but I cannot repeat the whole documentation in a comment and as I'm not a native English speaker, the documentation might be easier to understand than what I write ;)

Comment: @FeRtoll: I would be glad if you explain me why you have been upset about my reference to the documentation? I did not mean to offend you. I tried my best to explain the differences between `filter` and `find`  in the limited space of the comments. But I can again answer your question: There is no better, because `find` and `filter` do different things and yes, `find` does not work in this situation.

Comment: @Felix Kling - tolld you... nm. just forget it. lets not spam this question with comments! :D its bad this have no private messages or something like that! Its just that i dont like when someone copy paste documentations or other people links or things like that! Dont write here anymore i will not respond :D i dont want be spammer! :D Nothing against you, all fine! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `:contains`

```
$(that).contains("[name]").dostuff();
```

Comment: `.contains` is for selecting elements containing some text. In your case you search for `:[name]`. The OP wants to filter elements having the `name` *attribute*.